# Как вывести названия месяцев без склонения в calendar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, calendar

Нужно вывести названия месяцев без склонения с помощью модуля calendar.
Пишу на python 3.6

```
import calendar
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8') 
for name in calendar.month_name:
    print(name.capitalize())
```

Выходит:

```
>>> Января Февраля Марта Апреля Мая Июня Июля Августа Сентября Октября Ноября Декабря
```

Нужно:

```
>>> Январь Февраль Март Апрель Май Июнь Июль Август Сентябрь Октябрь Ноябрь Декабрь
```

Comment: А `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B")` что возвращает?

Comment: @mkkik тоже самое >>> апреля

Comment: @MaxU неправильно указан locale выдает >>>locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

Comment: на моей машине (Ubuntu), уже нужный ввод печатается.

Comment: Если только один язык поддерживать нужно, то почему список не использовать? Что у вас `icu.SimpleDateFormat('LLLL', icu.Locale('ru')).format(time.time())` из PyICU выводит? Или `format_date(DT.date.today(), format='LLLL', locale='ru')` из `babel.dates`?

Comment: Странно, запустил этот код у меня всё нормально... У меня windows 10. Может с ос связано

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, это "стрельба из пушки по воробьям", но можно использовать библиотеку [Pymorphy2](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), с помощью которой можно привести названия месяцев в "нормальную форму" (именительный падеж, единственное число). Делается это буквально парой дополнительных строк, полезно уметь ей пользоваться, мало ли где ещё пригодится:

```
import calendar
import locale
import pymorphy2

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8') 
for name in calendar.month_name:
    print(morph.parse(name)[0].normal_form.capitalize())
```

Вывод:

```
Январь
Февраль
Март
Апрель
Май
Июнь
Июль
Август
Сентябрь
Октябрь
Ноябрь
Декабрь
```